# What is the meaning of 'zu zweit'?

Tags: meaning

I've seen this phrase a few times in songs. Like for example,  there's a line in a song that goes "Siehst du mit mir sind viele schon zu zweit" and another one that goes "Nicht ich zu zweit". I've tried looking for translations for this phrase but it says "for two". I don't quite understand this. Can someone explain this for me?

The first song is "Tupac" by Noah Levi:

> Du wohnst gegenüber und jeden Abend kann ich sehen
> Dass bei dir immer das Licht brennt
> Selbst wenn andere schlafen gehen
> Frag mich was bei dir los ist
> Liegst du auch grade wach
> Machst du dich auch verrückt, wenn es dunkel ist nachts
> Vielleicht kenn ich dich nicht, doch ich kenn das Gefühl
> Vielleicht kennst Du mich nicht, aber spürst was ich spür
>
> Fühl dich nicht allein
> **Siehst du mit mir sind viele schon zu zweit**
> Es gibt so viele Lichter die brennen wie deins
> Es ist meistens nicht so wie es anfangs scheint

The second song is "Nicht ich" by Jannik Brunke:

> Und ich weiß, und ich weiß, und ich weiß und ich weiß nicht mehr
> Wer ich bin, eh, wer ich bin
> Gib mir Halt, gib mir Herz, gib mir dich und ich gebe dir
> Nichts zurück, yeah, nichts zurück, yeah
>
> Ich pass' da nicht rein
> Falscher Ort, falsche Zeit
> Plan mich nicht mit ein
> **Ich bin nicht ich zu zweit**

Comment: Can you name the songs? I think we need more of the context.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please edit your post to include song/author and a few more lines of quoted songs to get context. Like two/three sentences around the quote.

Answer (score 11):

The lyrics of the first example are wrong. I didn't know that song and therefore searched for a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2telRUt6zg). The singer kind of mutters and it's easy to mishear the line. It's not

> Siehst du mit mir sind <s>viele</s> schon zu zweit

but

> Siehst du, mit mir sind **wir** schon zu zweit.

**Wir sind zu zweit** simply means **we are two** (in the sense of *couple* or *pair*). So the two lines together: *Don't feel alone. You see - with me we are already two*.

In the second example

> Plan mich nicht mit ein
> Ich bin nicht ich zu zweit

means something like *Don't count me in. I'm not myself when we are together.* or *I'm not myself as part of a couple*.

Some more examples for the usage of *zu zweit*:

- Duschen zu zweit spart Wasser und Zeit.
  *Showering as a couple saves water and time.*
- Ich würde gern mehr Zeit zu zweit mit dir verbringen.
  *I would like to have some more alone time with you.*
- Die Ehe ist der Versuch, zu zweit mit Problemen fertig zu werden, die man allein niemals gehabt hätte.
  *Matrimony is the attempt of a couple to solve problems they would never have had as singles.*

Comment: "Sind viele schon zu zweit" is correct, it means "many are already paired up", in this specific case "here on my side/place many are already paired up".

Comment: @vonbrand He is singing: "sind wir schon zu zweit". In addition I think your translation is very far-fetched.

Answer (score 0):

*For two* is likely to be wrong, but none of your examples is easily understandable.

The meaning is something like *as a pair/couple* or *as a group of two* but as often, a better translation requires specific context.

Comment: Why don't you wait for specific context then? You even say the example is not easily understandable, for all we know, it might not even be the correct phrase.

Comment: @infinitezero: I'm not overly confident, that additional context arrives or suggests something entirely different. But for the phrase as such at least my answer still holds

Comment: If no additional context arrives I think it's safe to say an answer is not that important to OP.

Comment: @infinitezero: While I agree, I don't see an impact of  your comment. The question will remain and others with the same question may  stumble upon it and prefer a short answer to a comment containing a clarification request.

Comment: They are free to post a question with additional context though.

Answer (score 0):

In the second song it says "I'm not myself [second "ich"] when we are together ["zu zweit"]".

Answer (score -3):

"Zu zweit" in both of these songs looks like it means something like the 'the dark side of me' or more accurately 'the lost side of me' in the sense of losing touch with reality. The first song tells the listener "not to feel alone because there are many of me" as in driven crazy by his/her yearning for their love interest across the street.
The second song blatantly states the the writer doesn't know who they are and don't fit in anywhere and not to 'plan any future for me' with the last line declaring "Ich bin nicht ich zu zweit" as in 'I'm not me, I don't know who I am or if I even exist.'

Comment: *Zu zweit* means *the dark / lost side of me*? Where did you come up with such an idea? *Zu zweit* simply means *two (people)*.

Comment: I thought that "looks like it means" made it clear that this was my interpretation. I'll be more careful next time. What is your interpretation of these songs and how "zu zweit" should be translated? Can you explain?